# Is my particular solution of $ {(3xy + y^2)}\ dx + {(x^2 + xy)}\ dy = 0 $ for $x=1$ and $y=1$ correct?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, differential

> Find the particular solution to 
>   $$
> {(3xy +  y^2)}\ dx + {(x^2 + xy)}\ dy = 0
> $$
>   *for* $x=1$ *and* $y=1$.

**My Solution**
$$
\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{3xy+y^2}{x^2+xy}
$$

Substituting $y=vx$ , $\frac{dy}{dx}=v+x\frac{dv}{dx}$

$$
v+x\frac{dv}{dx}=-\frac{3vx^2+x^2v^2}{x^2+vx^2}
$$

$$
v+s\frac{dv}{dx}=-\frac{3v+v^2}{1+v}
$$

$$
x\frac{dv}{dx}=-\frac{2v^2+4v}{v+1}
$$

$$
\frac{v+1}{2v^2+4v}=-\frac{dx}{x}
$$

$$
\frac{(2v+2)}{v^2+2v}=-4\frac{dx}{x}
$$
$$
\int\frac{(2v+2)}{v^2+2v}=-4\int\frac{dx}{x}
$$

$$
\log |v^2+2v| = -4\log|x|+\log C 
$$

$$
\log |v^2+2v| = \log\frac{C}{x^4}
$$

$$
|v^2+2v|=\frac{C}{x^4}
$$

$$
|y^2+2xy|=\frac{C}{x^2}
$$

Substituting $x=1$ and $y=1$, $C=3$

The answer is 
$$
|{(y^2 + 2xy)}|= \frac{3}{x^2}
$$

***The answer in the book is left till here only,but what I did after this was as follows***

$$
 (y^2 + 2x y) = \pm\frac{3}{x^2}
$$

And then rejecting 
$$
 (y^2 + 2x y) = -\frac{3}{x^2}
$$

*As it does not satisfy $x=1$, $y=1$*

So According to me the particular solution is 
$$
 (y^2 + 2x y) = \frac{3}{x^2}
$$

Whose answer is correct *my or book's*?

Comment: How did you get the absolute value by the way?  Shouldn't you have gotten $$\text{d}\left(x^2y^2+2x^3y\right)=0\,,$$ and so $$x^2y^2+2x^3y=c$$ for some constant $c$ (or a *local constant* depending on whether $x>0$ or $x<0$)?  So, at the end, as you did, the answer is $$y^2+2xy=\frac{3}{x^2}\text{ for }x>0\,,$$ or $$y=\sqrt{x^2+\frac{3}{x^2}}-x\text{ for }x>0\,.$$  (Unfortunately, you do not know the solution for $x<0$, due to the barrier at $x=0$.)

Comment: Also, what does this sentence mean: "The book does not reject one solution by removing mod"?  What is *removing mod*?

Comment: _@Batominovski It means the answer contains mod._

Comment: @Batominovski And I don't get what you did .

Comment: What is *mod*?  Where does it appear?

Comment: @Batominovski Mod is *MODULUS function.*

Comment: Oh, you mean the absolute value?  Don't write something only for yourself to understand.  It is not usual to say "mod" for the absolute value or the modulus function.

Comment: And as I said, I don't get why absolute value appears in your work.  You have to show us how you got it.

Comment: @Batominovski One needs to be ***Flexible*** in The field of Mathematics!

Comment: Flexibility does not mean you can simply write anything that is not widely used and expect people to understand what you say.  That is laziness.

Comment: @Batominovski I already wrote the final answer.  You need to properly see it what I am asking.

Comment: You didn't show us how the "mod" appears in your first equation.  As such, I am closing the topic because of the lack of context.  You are asking us about why the book does not seem to have "mod" but you are not showing us why you get "mod."  Saying "upon solving the equation [...]" is insufficient.  We need to see the steps you took.

Comment: @Batominovski So you are asking me to show a one page answer which ultimately would be of no use

Comment: Yes.  You want to know whether you are correct, but you are not showing your work of the essential part?

Comment: @Batominovski Ok then , I am editing it .

Comment: @Batominovski I edited the post , you can recheck it now .

Comment: And you think that the one-page answer is irrelevant?  It is very crucial to understand what is going on with your question.

Comment: @Batominovski got what you were trying to say

Answer (score 3):

Neither you nor the book is correct.  Both are partially correct, but not correct entirely.  The false step is the belief that
$$\int\,\frac{1}{t}\,\text{d}t=\ln|t|+\text{constant}\,.$$
Since $t=0$ is not in the domain of the function $t\mapsto\dfrac1t$, what is correct is saying that
$$\int\,\frac1t\,\text{d}t=\ln|t|+c(t)\,,$$
where $c:(-\infty,0)\cup(0,\infty)\to\mathbb{C}$ is a locally constant function.  That is, for some constants $c_-$ and $c_+$ which are not necessarily the same, we have
$$c(t)=\begin{cases}c_-&\text{if }t<0\,,\\c_+&\text{if }t>0\,.\end{cases}$$

Therefore, what is safe to say is that
$$|v^2+2v|=\frac{\tilde{\Gamma}(x,v)}{x^4}$$
for some locally constant function $\tilde{\Gamma}$ in two variables with domain $\Omega:=\big(\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\} \big)\times \big(\mathbb{R}\setminus\{-2,0\}\big)$.  You can remove the absolute value and say
$$v^2+2v=\frac{\Gamma(x,v)}{x^4}$$
for some locally constant $\Gamma:\Omega\to\mathbb{C}$.

From the initial condition $(x,y)=(1,1)$ (whence $(x,v)=1$) that you are dealing with the connected component $(0,\infty)\times (0,\infty)$ of $\Omega$.  You can take $\Gamma(x,v)$ to be a constant $C$ there, which you found out that $C=3$.  That is,
$$y^2+2xy=x^2(v^2+2v)=\frac{C}{x^2}=\frac{3}{x^2}\text{ for }x>0\,.$$
However, you cannot jump the boundary and deduce that $y^2+2xy=\dfrac{3}{x^2}$ for $x<0$ too.

Comment: I am in school and your answer is not for school level . Any other explanation you got ?

Comment: I am sure that this argument should work for high school students.  Notice that $\dfrac{1}{x}$ and $\ln|x|$ are undefined for $x=0$.  So, $f(a,b):=\displaystyle\int_a^b\,\frac{1}{x}\,\text{d}x$ cannot be defined if $0$ is in the interval $[a,b]$.  So, you can either define $f(a,b)$ when both $a,b>0$ or when both $a,b<0$.  In other words, the antiderivative of $\dfrac1x$ has a natural boundary at $x=0$.  So, the behavior of this antiderivative for $x<0$ can be independent from the behavior for $x>0$ (i.e., the two branches can have different constants of integration).

Comment: But as a sidenote, there is some merit to the common belief that $$\int\,\dfrac1x\,\text{d}x=\ln|x|+\text{constant}.\tag{*}$$  There is something known as the *Cauchy principal value integral* (sometimes denoted by $\text{PV}\int$).  It makes sense to say that $$\text{PV}\int\,\frac{1}{x}\,\text{d}x=\ln|x|+\text{constant}.$$  But unless you know what you are doing, dispel the belief (*) from your head.